# Fixing this proof of the simple connectedness of the $n$-sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, spheres

As we all know, the $n$-sphere ($n\ge 2$) is simply connected.

However, the way this was proven to me seemed somewhat complicated and I tried my hand at simplifying. My professor insists that my simplification is overlooking a key detail, but I don't understand what the failure is.

Can you explain it to me and if possible fix the mistake so that the proof is correct?

---

The proof in question:

Let $\gamma$ be a cycle of basis $p$ over the $n$-sphere.

Since the sphere is locally homeomorph to the space $R^n$ we can find a closed neighborhood $D$ at a point of the sphere which does not contain $p$ and it is homeomorph to a closed disk.

[image: Path]

We can think of $\gamma$ as homotopic to the product of some paths either outside $D$ or inside $D$. But since $D$ is contractible we can find an homotopy of each of this paths inside $D$ to a path with the same end points but which only traverses the border of $D$ (which is path-connected since $n\ge 2$).

[image: Homotopy]

This induces a global homotopy of $\gamma$ to a path $\gamma'$ which evades the interior of $D$, and thus we can puncture the $n$-sphere in a point in the interior of $D$ to end in a space homeomorphic to $R^n$, which is again contractible and thus we can find an homotopy from $\gamma'$ to the constant path.

This shows that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a constant path, and thus the $n$-sphere is simply connected. $\square$

My professor points out that the step where the global homotopy is induced is not trivial, but I do not see how it fails.

Comment: (I did not drew a cycle in the sphere but I hope the intention is clear)

Comment: Well the premiage of your disc by $\gamma$ is a compact subset of $I$ but it can be very messy, e.g a cantor subset. Constructing the global homotopy out of  each individual homotopy will require more than a simple induction, and will also be messy.

Comment: @A.Rod What is premiage? And don't we have the construction justified by the gluing lemma?

Comment: Oh **preimage**

Comment: @Jsevillamol preimage.

Comment: Preimage is the inverse image.
On your picture the path/loop $\gamma$ is "nice" and the preimage is a finite union of closed intervals. With an arbitrary loop $\gamma$ we cannot say much more than $\gamma^{-1}(D)$ is a compact subset of $I$, such a set is not a finite union of intervals in general. How do you proceed then?

Comment: @A.Rod Can't we somehow demonstrate easily that every path fragment in the disk which reaches the interior has an interval with more that one point as its preimage? Then we only care about those, and we can proceed happily

Comment: Well you can certainly say that the preimage of the interior of the disc is a countable union of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: @A.Rod can you expand on the reason why? Also, is this good enough to fix the proof?

Comment: The reason is that $U=\gamma^{-1}(D^\circ)$ is open in $I$, it is a standard fact that an such an open subset is a countable union of disjoint intervals, in fact as the base point of your loop is supposed to be outisde $D$ you may even assume that $U$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals. The reason for this is very simple, take $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}$, and for each rational $a$ take $I_a$ to be a maximal open interval contained in $V$.
It should be enough to complete the proof, after all your reasonning now becomes very similar to the proof of the cellular approximation lemma.

Comment: Be careful when you write it you need to make sure that the homotopy you choose is relative to the end points of your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is pretty much the argument you get by examining the proof of the van Kampen theorem which apply to this case.  It works out better if $D$ is an open set.  Let $x\in D$, let $U$ be an open disk containing $D$, and let $V=S^n-\{x\}$.  That way, $\{U,V\}$ is an open cover of $S^n$, with both $U$ and $V$ contractible (and $U\cap V$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$, but this does not matter for the proof --- all that matters is that it is path connected).

Since $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ and $\gamma^{-1}(V)$ are unions of open intervals and $I$ is compact, we can write $\gamma=\gamma_1*\gamma_2*\dots*\gamma_m$ for finitely many $\gamma_i$, with each $\gamma_i$ lying entirely within $U$ or $V$.  For a $\gamma_i$ lying entirely in $U$, as you note this path can be homotoped to lie within $U\cap V$, keeping the endpoints fixed (say by choosing such a path then doing a linear homotopy, viewing $U$ as being an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$).  Thus, every $\gamma$ is homotopic to a path lying within $V$, and $V$ is contractible.